# Opensource-Video editor for android?

Tags: android, open-source, video-editing

Is there an video editor like  *Powerdirector* but **Opensource** for **android** that can do

- Chroma key
- Multiple video and audio tracks

without any coding/terminal ?

Comment: Do you mean open source, so you can examine/re-codeit yourself, or do you just mean 'free' to use?

Comment: I don't know which app includes what specific features – but consulting with [my corresponding app listing](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/foto_video) the question seems to stop at "open source" already. None at F-Droid, and none in my list mentioning its source. // @Tetsujin I assume Abhinav really means "open source", as simply "free" would be met by Powerdirector (though you pay with data for it, going by the list of 12 included trackers).